# How to change route name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes, rails-routing

I'm working in a RoR project and i have some routes that i want to change how this route paths is displayed on the browser.

My route:

```
get 'campaigns/:slug' => 'campaigns#show'
```

Result:

```
http://localhost:3000/campaigns/cdlcuiaba
```

What i want:

```
http://localhost:3000/cdlcuiaba
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do that because when hitting a URL like `/campaigns` you will be redirected to the CampaignsController#show action with `params[:slug]` equal to `"campaigns"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be warned that this is highly non-recommended, but can be done as follows (ordering matters):

```
get '/admin' => 'admin:show'
get '/:slug' => 'campaigns#show'
```

**EDIT** In your comments, you mentioned that you would like `/admin` *not* to be treated by `campaigns#show` so I edited the answer to reproduce such behavior. I must say though that this is **highly not recommended** - reasons should be clear by reading the comments.

Comment: But i have others routes like: http://localhost:3000/admin, so when i access any of this routes i will be redirect for the campaigns controller

Comment: @Henrique yes, that is to be expected. How would Rails (or any other software) know if `admin` is an object id or has some special meaning (e.g. is the name of another resource)? Think of the root `/` as just another path. Think if your question makes sense if we were using another path instead of `/`, say `mypath/`: once we define `mypath/:id` as a `show` for some resource, we would expect `mypath/something` to return a `show` of the `something` resource.

Comment: @Henrique I've updated my answer to reproduce the behavior you requested.

Comment: @brito You do make a good point - that would not be the rails(tm) way, since it is good practice to make the routes as intuitive as possible. However, rails would know to differentiate - `routes` are read, and matched, from top to bottom (as you have highlighted in your answer).

Comment: @brito Thanks very much for the explanation, i know that's not good way, so i quit this task, maybe in the future this task will cause many other problems for my application. Thanks.